# Mysql Get table result between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I know my question is similar to other question already answered but my issue is different because I need some alternative or advice no how to go the other way around.

My issue is: I want to get values between either two dates or one according to what user wants..

[image]

When User request data of one day.. php query data successful.. but problem is when data requested is between two dates..

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `meta_receipt_data` 
WHERE  `meta_transaction_date` >= '$first_date' AND
`meta_transaction_date` <= '$second_date' ");
        return $query->result();
```

I get an empty set...

So I thought may be the values are not submitted correct.. so I echoed the values to see if they are correct or not. I find they are correct...

> $first_date = 09/13/2014; 
>       $second_date = 09/19/2014;

But if I try to put the value like

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `meta_receipt_data` 
WHERE  `meta_transaction_date` >= '09/13/2014' AND
`meta_transaction_date` <= '09/19/2014' ");
        return $query->result();
```

I get my result back correct.. so is there anything am doing it wrong??

Comment: What are the datatypes on `$first_date`,`$second_date` and the column `meta_transaction_date`?

Comment: `$first_date` & `$second_date` are string but they came from array  `$first_date = $date['range_one'];` & `$second_date = $date['range_two'];` same as to    `meta_transaction_date` I have set the type as Varchar...

Comment: did you try between function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of `meta_transaction_date` to `DATE` as that is what it is! Also use the standard `'yyyy-mm-dd'` when passing in `DATE`s.

Your problem probably stems from string ordering of the `'mm/dd/yyyy'` US date format which is horrible for coding. If you wish to display the `DATE` in this format, convert it when `SELECT`ing the final output.

Comment: It is true.. Arth.. I knew it wasn't wise to use that format for date but those value came from JavaScript date_picker so I had this idea of escaping extra hustle and I though to deal with date on my own way.. but know I follow your advice and use the `DATE` though it did not work ..  But I found that the value had space before and after so I use `$first = trim($first_date);` and problem solved.. Thank Boss

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a built in function called Between that you can use like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date_column BETWEEN 'start_date_parameter' AND 'end_time_parameter'
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: On Mysql console the code works even when I use the actual dates in my php code.. but if I substitute the values with variable...I get empty set... Your code work on sql console but in my php code nothing empty set

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the date first , and then with `between` statement:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `meta_receipt_data` 
WHERE `meta_transaction_date` BETWEEN    
date_format(str_to_date('$first_date', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
date_format(str_to_date('$second_date', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')");
```

Comment: I use this trick... and I think I will need it on next thing but I just go with the long way and `explode('/', $first_date);` they I assign each value to associative array.. It was long booring but thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `meta_receipt_data`
WHERE  `meta_transaction_date` >= '09/13/2014'
AND `meta_transaction_date` <= '09/19/2014' ");
```

Since the above seems to be working fine, the problem is in your code.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT `meta_transaction_date` FROM meta_receipt_data WHERE
                           meta_transaction_date BETWEEN "
                          .date( "Y-M-d", ( strtotime($first_date) ) )." AND "
                          .date( "Y-M-d", ( strtotime($second_date) ) ) );
```

A word of advice, do not use queries like `SELECT *` as they will degrade performance of your application. And I just read in your comment to your own question:

> I have set the type as Varchar

Do not do that. It is best to use the DATE type to store dates. You can use the query:

```
ALTER TABLE `meta_receipt_data`
MODIFY `meta_transaction_date` DATE NOT NULL;`
```

Well, that is assuming you wish to keep the column to not accept null values.

Comment: sorry had forgotten to write the answer :P

Comment: I found that the value had space before and after so I use `$first = trim($first_date);` and problem solved.. and I also change the column type to `DATE` Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I found that the value had space before and after so I use `$first = trim($first_date);` and problem solved...